# Is it possible to make a request while reading a file from a URL?

Tags: node.js, request, fs

Is it possible to read a file from a URL when doing a request?

```
var options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'url': 'http://172.19.64.193:8080/services/update?id=AkDwkm5bKo0ARvuvTaM7yj',
    'headers': {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authToken
    },
    formData: {
        'Filedata': {
            'value': fs.createReadStream('image.jpg').pipe(request.put('https://www.worldcocoafoundation.org/wp/uploads/image.jpg')),
            'options': {
                'filename': '7798153810500.jpg',
                'contentType': null
            }
        }
    }
};
request(options, function (error, response) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    console.log(response.body);
});
```

When doing the createReadStream with pipe(), it throws the error:

```
TypeError: request.put is not a function
```

Comment: Where does `request` come from?  Can you show the code that defines that variable?  It appears that perhaps you've accidentally overriden the `request` variable with something that isn't the NPM module by that same name and thus, there is no `.put()` method because this `request` variable isn't the `request` module from NPM, but something else.

Comment: Where did you go?  Please don't just post and disappear.  We cannot help you if you do that.

Comment: Yes, the request was overriden. But now I'm getting the error:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'image.jpg'

Comment: If you're saying that this `fs.createReadStream('image.jpg')` generates ENOENT, then that is pretty self-explanatory that `image.jpg` is not being found in the current directory. Perhaps it needs a correct path?  Or, your code hasn't finished putting it there yet?

Comment: Isn't it read from the URL and then downloaded?

Comment: No.  Your code attempts to READ from `image.jpg` and then send that resulting file to your URL as the body of the request.  `.pipe()` works like this `readable.pipe(writable)`.  To read from that URL, you would need something like `request.get(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('image.jpg'))`.  See [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options).

Comment: FYI, you really shouldn't be writing new code with the `request()` library as it has been deprecated.  There is a list of alternatives [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143).  My favorite is `got()` which can do the same structures you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error you get, it appears that the `request` symbol is overriden by some other definition and thus is not the `request` library that you expect it to be.

You will need to change the variable/function parameter name that is overriding it so they do not conflict.